# Sitecore Publishing behaviour when there's an error

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

What happens when there's an error during the sitecore publishing process? Let's say the connection to the target server gets lost.

Remain the already published items published or does Sitecore roll back the whole publish job?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the connection to the target server is lost, it is a bit hard to rollback the already published items. Sitecore leaves the already published items unharmed.